# how many standard deviation moves are required to get to a certain level

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

Say I have a portfolio which has a standard deviation of 8%.

To lose 25% of its value how many standard deviations would it need to move?

Is it simply a 3 standard deviation move required to lose this much?

Comment: You are mixing up price and return.  Which is it that you have statistics on?

Comment: I have the returns. The volatility is 8%

Comment: Well, if you only have returns there is little you can say about the price.  You could have $8\%$ return on a stock which trades at $.01$ or one that trades at $100$.

Comment: More to the point...even if $\sigma = 0$, the price would surely get to $25$ over time (assuming it started below $25$).  Indeed, the price would climb steadily to infinity.

Comment: ah sorry I see what you are saying. If we are saying that the price is at 8 then which statement above is true?

Comment: Neither one, Well, as I say, the question is meaningless unless you specify a time frame.  Remember, volatility is based on a very short time increment.  Even a big one day move is unlikely to get the stock to $25$. So...I think you need to rethink what you are asking.

Comment: the volatility is an annualised figure

Comment: Of course it is, but your question did not indicate any time frame.  Did you mean to speak of $1$ year?  Nothing in the post suggests that. Please take a moment to edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Note:  I find it hard to imagine that you actually meant a year, starting from a price of $8$.  That's a return of $212.5\%$, not sensibly measured in your $\sigma$ units.

Comment: @lulu apologies. I have edited my question, this field is not my normal area. I re-read the topic required and realised I was asking the wrong question

Comment: Well, it's a strange portfolio...mean return of $0$ but very volatile. Normally investors expect to be compensated for accepting volatile assets, and wouldn't tolerate a $0\%$ expected return.   But if that is really what you mean, then yes.  You are talking about a $3.125\sigma $ move.